# cleaning android app user activity data

Tags: android, data-analysis, data-extraction

I have the *raw data of user activity on an android app*. I failed to find a way to clean this data and bring it to a tabular **comma separated** form. I have to load this data into **R**.

> `{"event_type":"ActionClicked","event_timestamp":1451****72592,"arrival_timestamp":1456****18415,"event_version":"3.0","application":{"app_id":"7ffa58d******6cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9****3-0487-44ec-be27-1****d15df74","package_name":"com.think.abcd","sdk":{"name":"aws-sdk-android","version":"2.2.2"},"title":"Vito","version_name":"1.0.2.1","version_code":"3"},"client":{"client_id":"43***52e-5b7c-4e99-9216-831***5b0c07","cognito_id":"us-east-1:4****b89-f382-4975-a1a1-dd8a****dd0c"},"device":{"locale":{"code":"en_GB","country":"GB","language":"en"},"make":"samsung","model":"GT-S5312","platform":{"name":"ANDROID","version":"4.1.2"}},"session":{"session_id":"c1**0c07-2015**31-17**52586","start_timestamp":145158**525**},"attributes":{"OfferID":"*****","Category":"*****","CustomerID":"***"},"metrics":{}}
>   {"event_type":"_session.start", ...`

Could anyone please help me with a tool or package or a method to extract the relevant attribute values from this data.

Comment: This is just json: to visualise it properly you can sites such as this one: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: great! Thank-you @M0CH1R0N